# Copy rotation From child to parent without IK

Tags: bones, constraints

I made a constraint on the shoulder bone of my character so that when the forearm bone moves, the shoulder follows the rotation with 50% influence. But it causes a dependency cycle and the movement won't update and cause some weird deformation on the mesh.

https://streamable.com/mtlcj

is there any way to accomplish that or something simmilar that causes no errors?